# Update widget after service finishes downloading data from internet

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

i have multiple widgets with different ids. Then I have service that is downloading data with a few asynctasks. In my widgets, I have refresh button, that when i clicked on, I need to start service, that downloads the data through that asynctasks and after that, it will refresh the data in widgets. Any idead?

Thank you